# Approximation of the convergence order

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to show the following equation:

> Let $p>1$ be the convergence order of a sequence $(x_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$ that converges against $x$. Then $p$ can be approximated as:
>   $$ p \approx \frac{log(||x_{k+2}-x_{k+1}||)}{log(||x_{k+1}-x_k||)}$$

I took the definition of the convergence order and rearranged it:
$$||x_{k+1}-x|| \leq C||x_k-x||^p $$
$$\Rightarrow ln(||x_{k+1}-x||) \leq p*ln(C||x_k-x||)$$
$$\Rightarrow p \geq \frac{ln(||x_{k+1}-x||)}{ln(C||x_k-x||)}$$
$$\Rightarrow p \approx \frac{ln(||x_{k+2}-x_{k+1}||)}{ln(C||x_{k+1}-x_k||)}$$

My question: Can I simply "ignore"  the C, since it's a constant? Also, is what I did above correct? Thanks in advance.